# AssetsLibrary and music Library on iPhone

Tags: ios, assets

I am in trouble with my App and expecting your help.(forgive my poor english)

I tried to access the AssetsLibrary get the photos and videos, also access the music Library to get the musics import from iTunes( musics imported to my iPhone, I just want to get music Data from my iPhone.)

---

Now the trouble comes:

1.AssetsLibrary - I got the assets, and can view them( photos&videos ); But I want to 
upload them, is there any way ? (I can get the image data by using myAsset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage, and then upload it, but I can't do this to a videoAsset, is it possible to get the video data?)

2.music Library - For now I just know one way can access musics ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), and I can play, pause, view these items; my question is : Is there any way I can get the music data?

---

In a word, is there any way can get the video data and the music data on my iPhone?

Thanks for your time, any help will be my great appreciate。
Somebody help me.

Comment: please accept the answer when you find the library

Comment: also this question is tagged iOS but you say MAC in your question.

Comment: my fault, I mean import music from my mac iTunes to my iPhone, and I want to get the media data from my iPhone.

Comment: TSLibrary can export data from itunes library on iOS, on Mac its a simple file copy from the itunes library.

Comment: Seems can solve my problem, I doubt if the app store will reject my app after using this library, hopes not.

Comment: it doesnt use private APIs, in fact I had an app just get approved using it.  Tons of apps do.

Comment: thank you fro your explanation. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google TSLibraryImport - it can do what you need.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll check it now. hopes can get the media data.